# config file with a dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, config, configobj

So I am trying to use a dictionary inside a config file to store a report name to an API call.  So something like this:

```
report = {'/report1': '/https://apicall...', '/report2': '/https://apicall...'}
```

I need to store multiple reports:apicalls to one config value.  I am using ConfigObj.  I have read there [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#unrepr-mode), [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml) and it says I should be able to do it.  My code looks something like this:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj('settings.ini', unrepr=True)
for x in config['report']:
    # do something... 
    print x
```

However when it hits the config= it throws a raise error.  I am kinda lost here.  I even copied and pasted their example and same thing, "raise error".  I am using python27 and have the configobj library installed.

Comment: Which error is being thrown? Can you paste the full stack trace here?

Answer (score 5):

If you're not obligated to use `INI` files, you might consider using another file format more suitable to handle `dict`-like objects. Looking at the example file you gave, you could use `JSON` files, Python has a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to handle it.

Example:

JSON File "settings.json":

```
{"report": {"/report1": "/https://apicall...", "/report2": "/https://apicall..."}}
```

Python code:

```
import json

with open("settings.json") as jsonfile:
    # `json.loads` parses a string in json format
    reports_dict = json.load(jsonfile)
    for report in reports_dict['report']:
        # Will print the dictionary keys
        # '/report1', '/report2'
        print report
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue trying to read ini file:

```
[Section]
Value: {"Min": -0.2 , "Max": 0.2}
```

Ended up using a combination of config parser and json:

```
import ConfigParser
import json
IniRead = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
IniRead.read('{0}\{1}'.format(config_path, 'config.ini'))
value = json.loads(IniRead.get('Section', 'Value'))
```

Obviously other text file parsers can be used as the json load only requires a string in the json format. One issue I did run into was the keys in the dictionary/ json string need to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your config file `settings.ini` should be in following format:

```
[report]
/report1 = /https://apicall...
/report2 = /https://apicall...
```

---

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

config = ConfigObj('settings.ini')
for report, url in config['report'].items():
    print report, url
```

If you want to use `unrepr=True`, you need to

Answer (score 2):

This config file used as input is fine:

```
report = {'/report1': '/https://apicall...', '/report2': '/https://apicall...'}
```

This config file used as input

```
flag = true
report = {'/report1': '/https://apicall...', '/report2': '/https://apicall...'}
```

generates this exception, which looks like what you are getting:

```
O:\_bats>configobj-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\_bats\configobj-test.py", line 43, in <module>
    config = ConfigObj('configobj-test.ini', unrepr=True)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\configobj.py", line 1242, in __init__
    self._load(infile, configspec)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\configobj.py", line 1332, in _load
    raise error
configobj.UnreprError: Unknown name or type in value at line 1.
```

With the `unrepr` mode set on, you are required to use valid Python keywords. In my example I used `true` instead of `True`. I'm guessing you have some other settings in your `Settings.ini` which are causing the exception.

> The unrepr option allows you to store and retrieve the basic Python data-types using config files. It has to use a slightly different syntax to normal ConfigObj files. Unsurprisingly it uses Python syntax. This means that lists are different (they are surrounded by square brackets), and strings must be quoted.
>
> The types that unrepr can work with are :
>
> strings, lists, tuples
> None, True, False
> dictionaries, integers, floats
> longs and complex numbers